# Excel Bring back Unique Record and description

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a table in excel that I am bringing in from Access.
I can get a unique Name from the list, but I don't know how to bring the description in the format below.

This is how the table in excel looks like:

```
  Name  Description
    John    Black
    John    Blue
    John    Black
    Mary    Green
    Mary    Blue
    Jim    Yellow
    Jim    Yellow
    Jim     Black
```

I want it to look like this so I'll have two field name and description will be both unique

```
Name       Description
John       Black, Blue
Mary       Green, Blue
Jim        Yellow, Black
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First Remove Duplicates. If `Name` is in A1, in C2:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1&", "&B2,B2)
```

in D2:

```
=A2=A3
```

Copy both down to suit. Select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, filter on ColumnD to select TRUE, delete selection, delete ColumnD and ColumnB.